# ERROR: column "country" is of type text[] but expression is of type record (SQLSTATE 42804)

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm, go-fiber

As a beginner, I want to know what I've did wrong in my code, I asked chatgpt, but it's not giving me good info. any help is appreciated.

```
web-1  | 2024/03/31 14:26:43 /usr/src/app/handlers/ads.go:59 ERROR: column "country" is of type text[] but expression is of type record (SQLSTATE 42804)
web-1  | [0.248ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "conditions" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","ad_id","age_start","age_end","gender","country","platform") VALUES ('2024-03-31 14:26:43.751','2024-03-31 14:26:43.751',NULL,5,20,30,('M'),('TW','JP'),('android','ios')) ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "ad_id"="excluded"."ad_id" RETURNING "id"
```

```golang
package models

import (
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type AD struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title      string       `json:"title" gorm:"type:text"`
    StartAt    time.Time    `json:"startAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    EndAt      time.Time    `json:"endAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    IsActive   bool         `gorm:"default:False;type:boolean"`
    Conditions []Conditions `json:"conditions"`
}

type Conditions struct {
    gorm.Model
    ADID     uint
    AgeStart int      `json:"ageStart" gorm:"default:0;type:integer"`
    AgeEnd   int      `json:"ageEnd" gorm:"default:100;type:integer"`
    Gender   []string `json:"gender" gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Country  []string `json:"country" gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Platform []string `json:"platform" gorm:"type:text[]"`
}
```

```golang
func CreateAd(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    ad := new(models.AD)
    if err := c.BodyParser(ad); err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
    }

    if IsAdAlive(*ad) {
        ad.IsActive = true
    } else {
        ad.IsActive = false
    }

    fmt.Println(ad)

    database.DB.Db.Model(models.AD{}).Create(&ad)
    return c.Status(200).JSON(ad)
}
```

I asked chatGPT, it said this:

*Review GORM Documentation: Ensure that you're using GORM's features correctly for handling arrays. GORM should abstract away the need to manually format arrays for PostgreSQL. If there's a discrepancy in how GORM expects arrays to be formatted versus what your PostgreSQL version expects, this could lead to issues. Checking the latest GORM documentation for array support or any open issues related to array handling could provide insights or solutions.*

but I can't find those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to `pq.StringArray` type, also include `"github.com/lib/pq"`

```golang
type Conditions struct {
    gorm.Model
    ADID     uint
    AgeStart int            `json:"ageStart" gorm:"default:0;type:integer"`
    AgeEnd   int            `json:"ageEnd" gorm:"default:100;type:integer"`
    Gender   pq.StringArray `json:"gender" gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Country  pq.StringArray `json:"country" gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Platform pq.StringArray `json:"platform" gorm:"type:text[]"`
}
```